# how to change span content within a div

Tags: javascript, html

How do I change the `span` content when a `div` block is clicked using JavaScript?

```js
var tiles = document.querySelector(".block2");
tiles.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName(".txt").innerHTML = "Hello";
});
```

```html
<div class="block1"><span class="txt">1</span></div>
<div class="block2"><span class="txt">2</span></div>
<div class="block3"><span class="txt">3</span></div>
```

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined"`. Also, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object. Check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) on that too.

Comment: Is there another way I can change the span without using getElementsByClassName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- get all blocks
- loop them
- add a click to each
- get the inner spans of the current block
- loop them
- change the `innerText`

```js
var tiles = document.querySelectorAll(".block1, .block2, .block3");
for (let tile of tiles) tile.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (let span of tile.querySelectorAll(".txt")) span.innerHTML = "Hello";
});
```

```html
<div class="block1"><span class="txt">1</span></div>
<div class="block2"><span class="txt">2</span></div>
<div class="block3"><span class="txt">3</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change all span innerText then,

```
let spans = document.getElementsByClassName("txt");

spans.forEach(element => {
  element.innerText = "Hello";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want apply the same logic to all items, set same class to all:

```
<div class="block"><span class="txt">1</span></div>
<div class="block"><span class="txt">2</span></div>
<div class="block"><span class="txt">3</span></div>
```

Then addEventListener to each block:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("block");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    item.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var span = this.getElementsByClassName("txt")[0];
      span.innerHTML = "Hello";
    });
}
```

Inside the function, "this" is the block clicked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all `div` that contains a class "**block**" using `querySelectorAll` and `wildcard`
2. Iterate on each `div` element and add `click` listener with a callback function
3. Once a div was clicked, get its first child using `firstChild` and replace its content using `innerHTML`

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll("[class*='block']");
blocks.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener("click", () => {
    e.firstChild.innerHTML = "Hello";
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="block1"><span class="txt">1</span></div>
<div class="block2"><span class="txt">2</span></div>
<div class="block3"><span class="txt">3</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch all divs. You can use for example this selector: `document.querySelectorAll('[class^="block"]');` Then you can assign ervery div a click event.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="block"]');

divs.forEach(d => {
  d.addEventListener("click", () => {
    d.firstChild.innerHTML = "Hello";
  });  
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1"><span class="txt">1</span></div>
<div class="block2"><span class="txt">2</span></div>
<div class="block3"><span class="txt">3</span></div>
```